# Locating servers IP address

Tags: networking, server, libgdx, ip, kryonet

I am making a game in Libgdx where a user(client) will be a host of the server himself
and only one other client can connect to him and play with him(likewise there might be multiple independent servers and pair of clients playing with each other like miniclip games)
but how will the other client locate host-client (or servers) IP?
I am using kryonet
Some guy suggested me to do NAT punching and stuff but I am totally confused.
Please help

(I am complete beginner to networking)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your clients to discover servers just in LAN, you can do broadcasting on the servers and sniffing on the clients. As they are in the same LAN, there should be no need for NAT.

Otherwise, you have to set up managers(servers for managing) on the Internet. Servers have to register themselves to a manager, clients ask a manager for servers information. As managers know both servers and clients public IP addresses, NAT should be easy once you think your managers as [STUN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3489) servers.

The most simple manager can be just a simple wraper over database/Redis with a server name/server ip/server metadata table. Details about how to implement it relies on your skill stack. To enable STUN, there are open source STUN server and client you can just pick up, e.g. [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn). No matter you put the STUN server into your manager or not, both your managers and STUN servers have to be published on the Internet (sure include AWS) where they have their own public IP.

Or you can let the managers to relay messages for servers and clients. But this way may be too complicated compares to previous. I would not recommend.

Comment: I am a complete networking beginner and at first i thought that whenever a user will host a server, i would upload his IP to somewhere on the cloud and let other clients search for  his IP(At that time i didnt knew about NAT and STUN). Now maybe you are right about managers but please guide me where and how to set them up. I am really keen to implement what i wish for.

Comment: "_If you want your clients to discover servers just in LAN, you can do broadcasting on the servers and sniffing on the clients._" That is the deprecated way to do it. In the modern world, we use multicast. Broadcast is a failed idea that the IETF did not even consider for IPv6 because it wastes network resources and is a security risk.